# Why am getting this error in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

hi am using android studio for app development.when i build the app i get this error. i don't know how to resolve this.Please help me to solve this error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Unsupported type 'String' in file /Users/win7/Documents/Android Development/Workspace/sample/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml
```

My app string xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Sample</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="firstscreenTitle">SCREEN ONE</string>
    <string name="secondscreenTitle">SCREEN TWO</string>
    <String name="thirdscreenTitle">SCREEN THREE</String>
</resources>
```

Comment: try cleaning your build once and then re-build it.

Answer (score 5):

```
<String name="thirdscreenTitle">SCREEN THREE</String>
```

Check here 'S' is in caps, it should be in small letter, change that to 's' it will work.

Change:

```
<String name="thirdscreenTitle">SCREEN THREE</String>

             to

<string name="thirdscreenTitle">SCREEN THREE</string>
```

Comment: Thanks for up voting. If the answer has solved your problem please do accept it as an answer along with up voting. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Change `<String name="thirdscreenTitle">SCREEN THREE</String>` in the line to `<string name="thirdscreenTitle">SCREEN THREE</string>`. You have used `String` with upper case `S`. You need to use lower case `s` for `string`.